# c# Returning with Console Background Color Changed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, enums

I'm trying to change the Background of the Console Application in c#

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.Clear();
Console.ReadKey();
```

This works perfectly fine, but when I try to do the same with the help of `enum` and method it returns.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.ConsoleColor' to 'string'

Here is the Code

```
public static string SetColor(RanngDe R)
{
    switch (R)
    {
        case RanngDe.Blue:
            return Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    }   
}


public enum RanngDe
{
    Blue,
    White,
    Red,
    Green
}
```

So far I've come to know that I have to Convert `System.ConsoleColor` to `String`, But I do not know how to implement it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Why is `SetColor()` returning a `string`? Shouldn't it be `void SetColor()`?

Comment: Why are you trying to return a string? Also - why define another enum - why not just stick with ConsoleColor enum so you do not need a switch statement.

Comment: @haim770 because void does not returns

Comment: @PaulF I learnt it this way, any other better method?

Comment: If you are only setting the background colour, then there is no reason to return anything. Or you could return the original enum or the ConsoleColor enum if you are going to use another enum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the signature of your method implies that you need to return a string. But you are returning a value of type `System.ConsoleColor` if you want to have this value as a string you can return it using the `ToString` method:

```
public static string SetColor(RanngDe R)
{
    switch (R)
    {
        case RanngDe.Blue:
            return (Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue).ToString();
    }
}
```

The Call of this example would look like this:

```
string c = SetColor(RanngDe.Blue);
```

Another solution would be of course to change the return type to `ConsoleColor`:

```
public static ConsoleColor SetColor(RanngDe R)
{
    switch (R)
    {
        case RanngDe.Blue:
            return Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        default: return ConsoleColor.Black;
    }
}
```

The Call of this example would look like this:

```
ConsoleColor c = SetColor(RanngDe.Blue);
```

But if you only want that the colour is assigned to the console then make you method simply `void`:

```
public static void SetColor(RanngDe R)
{
    switch (R)
    {
        case RanngDe.Blue:
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    break;
    }
}
```

The Call of this example would look like this:

```
SetColor(RanngDe.Blue);
```

Comment: this seems doable and I applied it too, one silly question, How do I call it in main method with parameter? with numbers or color names?
edit 1 : when I pass `0` it shows black screen with any other numbers it shows error.

Ok Solved it, I wasn't using `Console.Clear()`

Comment: @YashKaranke why do you reinvent the wheel? why did you make your own color enum? if already one exists?

Comment: I do not knew that, where is it located and how to use?

Comment: @YashKaranke `ConsoleColor.Blue` is already an enum. You are using it. You made an extra enum yourself, with a method that is not really necessary, because you can just simply use the `ConsoleColor` enum to assign the values directly. You can also use it in a switch/case.

Answer (score 2):

Change your method to return `void` instead of `string`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetColor(RanngDe.Blue);
        Console.Clear();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static void SetColor(RanngDe R)
    {
        switch (R)
        {
            case RanngDe.Blue:
                 Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                break;

                // other case statements
        }
    }
}
public enum RanngDe
{
    Blue,
    White,
    Red,
    Green
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use void function to set background color

```
public static void SetColor(RanngDe R)
{
    switch (R)
    {
        case RanngDe.Blue:
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            break;
        // rest of your code  
     }
}
```